# Qt - QML memory leaks when using Loader

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qml, loader

Firstly, I want to apologize for my bad English I have started learn 2 months ago.

And now to my problem. I want to use a component Loader to dynamic change a view file. Everything works good but memory leaks occur when I change a source variable in the Loader. I think isn't a mistake in my code but I don't know why it's happening.

I asked in the Qt Forum but nobody answered me.

I use Qt version 5.8, Windows 7

I believe you understand my English.
Thank you for help

Here is a little example which occurs the memory leaks.
http://www.filedropper.com/untitled2_1

Or here is the source code:

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include "testtimer.h"
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine *_engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine();
    QQmlComponent* _myComponent = new QQmlComponent(_engine, _engine);
    TestTimer test;
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(&test);
    QObject::connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),&test,SLOT(changeFile()));
    timer->start(10);
    _myComponent->loadUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    _engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("test",&test);
    QObject* _myComponentObj = _myComponent->create();
    return app.exec();
}
```

testtimer.cpp

```
#include "testtimer.h"

TestTimer::TestTimer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QUrl TestTimer::urlFile(){
    return _urlFile;
}

void TestTimer::changeFile(){
    if(page1)
        _urlFile=QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/Page2.qml"));
    else
        _urlFile=QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/Page1.qml"));
    page1=!page1;
    emit urlFileChanged();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Loader{
        source: test.urlFile
        onSourceChanged: gc()
    }
}
```

Page1.qml and Page2.qml (Pages has a same content only every page has a different color of rectangle):

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle{
    width:600
    height:600
    color:"red"
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that you have a memory leak? And why you calling gc() when source file changes?

Comment: I have run the application and the memory of app increase, slowly but increase. When I draw a rectangle with Canvas component then the memory of application increase really fast (as in the link example) then the application crash in 60 seconds.  I'm calling gc() only for a try but it doesn't help.

Comment: What version of Qt you're using? And do you really need to change the displayed page every 10 milliseconds?

Comment: Qt has many bugs, it could be this one https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58524 and if not report one.

Comment: Yeah, Sorry, I forgot write the version of Qt. I use 5.8 and Windows 7. No, I don't need to change the displayed page every 10 ms. This is only simple example for demonstrating the memory leaks. But the memory leaks occur even when I use e.g. 1 s time for refresh page and I think the memory leak mustn't occur neither by 10 ms nor by 1 seconds.